# variable was written, but never read?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling

Im getting the following warning `variable 'isTaken' was written to, but never read` on the following code :

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        var isTaken: Bool = false

        if textField == usernameTxt { var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text!)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0){

                    isTaken = true

                    }
                } else {
                    print("Username is available. ")
                }
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
          }
        }
        return true
    }
```

why am I getting the warning and how do I do away with it?

Comment: use `isTaken` globally if you really need to use it otherwise there seems no use of `isTaken`

Answer (score 18):

As error says `variable 'isTaken' was written to, but never read` means you are creating `isTaken` instance and assigning a value to it but it never used.

Answer (score 6):

Just eliminate the statements:

```
var isTaken: Bool = false
isTaken = true
```

Since the value is never used, defining and assigning to it accomplishes nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Basically it's saying that isTaken is assigned a value, but it doesn't actually do anything in your code. You are never using it or checking it's value, so it's simply an warning saying that the variable is unnecessary.

If you actually are using isTaken and the compiler doesn't realize for some reason, you could probably just add another line right after

```
isTaken = true;
```

that just says

```
isTaken;
```

Or make isTaken global if you're using somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Its a compiler warning to point out a dead code. You probably have copy pasted some code and removed some unwanted code. In doing so, usage of local variable `isTaken` is gone. So, its only being assigned a value and never used for materializing any benefits. You can either simply remove the code around `isTaken` or double check and put back the functionality around it :).

Answer (score 0):

It's warning you about a var that you set a value, but don't operate over it after.

Is very important keep your code clean and safe, so the xcode just gives you a little help with it.

```
isTaken = true;
```

Thats the point you set a value to *isTaken* variable.

Try to review your code and think about the use of this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do ***not*** do this, but the build setting is `GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE`. You can disable it, but again, do not.

I am adding the setting name here because I was searching to find it so that I could check its value in my project, but no question or answer mentioned its name.