# Swift iOS - How should one fix nested variables in If statement buildtime warnings

Tags: swift, warnings

For example I see warnings for the following code:

```
  var currentButtonLocation = self.view.frame
    if let button = view.viewWithTag(11) as? UIButton {
        currentButtonLocation = button.frame
    }
```

which produces the following error:

```
 Variable 'currentButtonLocation' was written to, but never read
```

Comment: Please refer to this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622790/variable-was-written-but-never-read)

Comment: you are not using the value of `currentButtonLocation `. either assign it to some other variable  or If you are not gonna use then remove it.

Comment: Thank you - I was confusing read vs written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There warning is fairly self-explanatory, it's just because you aren't ever using `currentButtonLocation`.

For example doing this would make the warning go away:

```
let newButtonFrame = currentButtonLocation
```

In general, you shouldn't be using vars (or constants for that matter) that you aren't actually going to read.